# Refactoring K-means algorithm in python, using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, refactoring, k-means

I'm studying K-means algorithm in python and have done this code on a intuitive way and wanna suggestions to optimizate and refactor it.

```
for i in range(N):
        for j in range(K):
               averages[i, j] = np.linalg.norm(trips[i] - centroids[j])**2

        for i in range(N):
                assigns[i] = int(np.argmin(averages[i]))

        for i in range(K):

                temp = np.zeros([F])
                temp = np.expand_dims(temp, axis=0)

                for j in range(N):
                        if(int(assigns[j]) == i):
                                temp = np.insert(temp, 0, trips[j], axis=0);

                temp = temp[:-1, :]

                if(temp.shape[0] > 0):
                        centroids[i] = temp.sum(axis=0) / temp.shape[0]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension, it should speed up a little bit:

```
for i1 in range(N):
        averages[i1] = [np.linalg.norm(trips[i1] - centroids[j])**2 for j in range(K)]

        assigns = [int(np.argmin(averages[i2])) for i2 in range(N)]

        for i3 in range(K):
                temp = np.zeros([F])
                temp = np.expand_dims(temp, axis=0)

                for j in range(N):
                        if(int(assigns[j]) == i3):
                                temp = np.insert(temp, 0, trips[j], axis=0)

                temp = temp[:-1, :]

                if(temp.shape[0] > 0):
                        centroids[i3] = temp.sum(axis=0) / temp.shape[0]
```

I renamed some indexes so i don't know if i have chosen the right ones in formulas. Anyway i don't recommed to use the same index in nested loops, it can create hard to find problems.